# How do you uninstall a Windows update in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

After patching a Windows 2003 server, I completely broke RightFax. How do I remove or uninstall the Windows updates I applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs.
Make sure "Show updates" is checked.
Then click on the update and click Remove.

Anders

Comment: The little check box at the top I've completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall the patch from

```
Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs
```

You'll have to check "Show updates" if it's not enabled to see all Windows Update patches.

Comment: If you have more than one server/computer where you want to uninstall the update, you could do that using the WSUS console. If you're running into problems, see this forums thread: http://www.wsus.info/forums/index.php?showtopic=6984

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively, you could do it from Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel (but make sure that "Show Updates" is ticked)... ;)

All joking aside, be aware also that there are some updates that cannot be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Go to add remove programs (appwiz.cpl) and tick the show updates box at the top. Then click the remove button beside the update you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of replies explaining how to remove the patch.

Here's something altogether more useful though - one of the June patches (don't have the KB with me right now) broke *everyones* RightFax servers, including a bunch of ours.  Captaris (the RightFax vendor) is aware, and rushing out a new patch to fix their software.

Just thought you'd like to know.